# python textual - run a loop besides the main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, textual

I'm using [textual](https://github.com/Textualize/textual) to display a ui in my console window. I start my class extending textual's App class by myclass.run().
Since I'm analyzing a camera signal using opencv, I now want to introduce a second loop that runs as long as the app runs to get and process the current image from opencv.
But I'm not sure how to start such a parallel loop using textual's API. The first thing that comes to my mind is a subthread but I fear textual might offer a better way.

Comment: https://github.com/Textualize/textual/discussions

Answer (score 1):

Textual offers a [Worker API](https://textual.textualize.io/guide/workers/), which provides a layer over threads to manage concurrent work. By the sounds of it, you want a *threaded* worker.

Comment: Hi Will, yes I saw the worker API but the docs made it look more like a way to run one-time-jobs in parallel. Where would I optimally start an endlessly running worker when on app start? Thanks for your fantastic library btw.

Comment: Workers are still the way to go. You could launch a worker in App.on_mount so that it will run when your app starts.